# Angular js - how to increment in html based on condition

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular repeat to populate form's fields dynamically. There is a scenario where I need to to notify user(show ! icon for duplicate fields). Below is code snippet:

```
<div ng-init="counter = 0">
  <div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
    <div ng-show="{{item.show}}">{{counter+1}}</div>
  </div>
  <div ng-show="{{counter > 1}}"> ! </div>
</div>
```

Counter variable only increment if its used like {{counter + $index}}, can it be possible without $index?

Comment: counter =  counter + 1 ?

Comment: `ng-show="item.show"`

Comment: What exactly you're looking for to notify for duplicate values.
Post your full code in fiddle.

Comment: What is "item"? How you tell which "item" is duplicated? It has duplicated ID? It is a number? A string? We can't read someone's mind, though.

Comment: @MarinTakanov, item has property show which is mentioned in code snippet.  ng-show="{{item.show}}

Comment: That still doesn't make any sence. By the code you provided, `show` is a  property which is not compared with any other `item`. You need to tell us how you determinate duplicated `items`? For instance, does `{address: 'baz', name: 'foo'}` and `{address: 'xyz', name: 'foo'}` are the same items? Here, if `name` is the property for comparison, the two items are same/duplicates.

Comment: @MarinTakanov , I can't paste the whole code here. I am not frequent user of this community but let me put my question again, is it possible to get counter increment based on condition in angular ng-repeat?

Comment: @cmApex of course it is, and if you want some sophisticated logic over that you can use methods in the controller. But the question doesn't make sense unfortunately, so please update it, by providing as much as information as you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning variables inside html is not officially supported.

But there is always a hack for what you asked:

```
<div ng-init="counter = 0"></div>
<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div style="display:none;">{{ n == 3 ? counter = "World!" : counter = n }}</div>
    <p>Hello {{ counter }}</p>
</div>
```

Notice that I used a non-displayed div for assigning the "counter" conditionally.

```
Output:
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello World!
Hello 4
Hello 5
```

**Answer to the 1st comment:**
When counter == 3, we divide it by 2.

```
<div ng-init="counter = 0"></div>
<div ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div style="display:none;">
        {{ counter = n }}
        {{ counter == 3 ? counter = counter / 2 : counter = counter }}
    </div>
    <p>Hello {{ counter }}</p>
</div>

Output:
Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 1.5
Hello 4
Hello 5
```

**Answer to the 3rd comment:**

I finally understood what you asked. Let me change the way to approach by using **ng-if** to keep the record of counter. I used ng-init to increment the counter when n is divisible by 2. You need to call $parent.$parent.counter to reach the original counter otherwise ng-if will create its own counter inside the child scope.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxwjtv6o/2/)

```
<div ng-init="counter = 0"></div>      
<div ng-repeat="n in [2,6,5,6,8,9,11] track by $index">
    <!-- ngRepeat child scope -->
    <div ng-if="n % 2 == 0"
    ng-init="$parent.$parent.counter = $parent.$parent.counter + 1"
    style="display:none;">
      <!-- ngIf also creates a child scope -->
    </div>
</div>      
<p>Counter = {{ counter }}</p>

Output:
Counter = 4
```

Comment: Thanks @KinoP but it will not serve the purpose. Is it possible to get count of number divided by 2 with your example? If yes, please paste code snippet, it will solve my problem.

Comment: @crmApex I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but check the updated answer above. The conditional expression of {{ boolean ? true case : false case }} is quite powerful.

Comment: Thanks. I want the **output: 2** because in your list n [1,2,3,4,5] only 2 & 4 is divisible by 2. Now, consider the fact of dynamic list. Let say n has [ 2,6,5,6,8,9,11], so **output: 4** as n has (2,6,6,8) which are divisible by 2. So, basically {{counter}} need to be incremented when an item of n is divided by 2 and remainder = 0.

Comment: @crmApex Check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I got what I have asked. **$parent.$parent.counter**, served the purpose.